# Most tricky/useful commands for gdb debugger

Tags: c, unix, gdb, debugging, dbx

Can you post your most tricky and useful commands while you run a debugger like gdb or dbx.

Comment: I found this documentation is good. https://scc.ustc.edu.cn/zlsc/sugon/intel/debugger/cl/index.htm#commandref/gdb_mode/cmd_condition.htm

Answer (score 141, accepted):

1. *backtrace full*: Complete backtrace with local variables
2. *up*, *down*, *frame*: Move through frames
3. *watch*: Suspend the process when a certain condition is met
4. *set print pretty on*: Prints out prettily formatted C source code
5. *set logging on*: Log debugging session to show to others for support
6. *set print array on*: Pretty array printing
7. *finish*: Continue till end of function
8. *enable* and *disable*: Enable/disable breakpoints
9. *tbreak*: Break once, and then remove the breakpoint
10. *where*: Line number currently being executed
11. *info locals*: View all local variables
12. *info args*: View all function arguments
13. *list*: view source
14. *rbreak*: break on function matching regular expression

Comment: `info locals` -- View all local variables; list -- view source; rbreak -- break on function matching regular expression.

Comment: source /path/to/macro/file
And all of my nifty macros are there to help me debug in seconds.

Comment: `set print object on` for polymorphic elements and `set print elements 0` are two commands I use very often. Pretty useful.

Comment: Also, `t a a bt` (meaning `thread apply all backtrace`). Could be used with (almost) all other commands. Especially useful with `bt full`.

Comment: Very useful information received in this thread , thank you all.

Answer (score 103):

Start gdb with a textual user interface

```
gdb -tui
```

Comment: I cannot believe this feature escaped me for all these years. Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: And another:  <minus> RET

Comment: or use [cgdb](https://cgdb.github.io/)

Comment: very nice features. Missed this so far...

Answer (score 45):

Starting in gdb 7.0, there is [reversible debugging](http://www.sourceware.org/gdb/news/reversible.html), so your new favourite commands are:

```
* reverse-continue ('rc') -- Continue program being debugged but run it in reverse
* reverse-finish -- Execute backward until just before the selected stack frame is called
* reverse-next ('rn') -- Step program backward, proceeding through subroutine calls.
* reverse-nexti ('rni') -- Step backward one instruction, but proceed through called subroutines.
* reverse-step ('rs') -- Step program backward until it reaches the beginning of a previous source line
* reverse-stepi -- Step backward exactly one instruction
* set exec-direction (forward/reverse) -- Set direction of execution.
```

Answer (score 21):

Instead of launching GDB with "-tui" param you can also switch to text mode after a while using by typing "wh".

Comment: Ctrl-a a to switch back to 'normal' command line view !

Comment: "-' can be used instaed of 'wh'. shorter the better..:)

Comment: `Ctrl-a a`? Is it a joke? Looks more like `tmux`/`screen` command. And doesn't work for me. It must be one of [as](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409540/how-to-close-layout-src-windows-in-gdb) per [docs](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI-Keys.html#TUI-Keys): `C-x C-a`, `C-x a`, `C-x A`.

Comment: It's actually `C-x a`. You can also switch views with `C-x 1` and `C-x 2` when in tui mode to see assembly as well (if need be).

Answer (score 16):

`thread apply all bt` or `thread apply all print $pc`: For finding out quickly what all threads are doing.

Comment: That was the command I was looking for a long-long time! It is really nasty to check all 30 threads one by one!

Comment: Very useful reply

Answer (score 6):

For example the macros defined in [stl-views.gdb](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=stl-views-1.0.3.gdb)

Answer (score 6):

scripting gdb is a good trick, other than that I like 
set scheduler locking on / off to prevent the running of other threads when you are stepping in one.

Comment: How do you set scheduler locking?

Comment: `set scheduler-locking on` inside gdb

Comment: how do you make this the default? I tried it .gdbinit but gdb prints

/home/omry/.gdbinit:1: Error in sourced command file:
Target 'None' cannot support this command.

Answer (score 6):

Using the `-command=<file with gdb commands>` option while firing up gdb. Same as `-x <command file>`. This command file can contain gdb commands like breakpoints, options, etc. Useful in case a particular executable needs to be put through successive debug runs using gdb.

Comment: You can also use the `-iex` option to add individual commands on the gdb command line.

Answer (score 4):

- Using *.gdbinit* (start up file where you can write macros and call from gdb). Place .gdbinit in your home directory so that it is picked up every time gdb is loaded
- *info threads* to list all the active threads, and f(#) -> # thread number you want to switch to
- sometime i use gdb to convert from hex to decimal or binary, its very handy instead of opening up a calculator

  - p/d 0x10  -> gives decimal equivalent of 0x10
  - p/t 0x10  -> binary equivalent of 0x10
  - p/x 256   -> hex equivalent of 256

Answer (score 4):

Instead of starting gdb with the option -tui to see a child process that contains a screen that highlights where the executing line of code is in your program, jump in and out of this feature with C-x o and C-x a. This is useful if you're using the feature and what to temporarily not use it so you can use the up-arrow to get a previous command.

Comment: you can change the focus to the command window using `focus cmd` so that the up/down arrows work.  You switch back using `focus src`.

Answer (score 3):

This can be useful, I am sure it could be improved though, help welcome:

```
define mallocinfo
  set $__f = fopen("/dev/tty", "w")
  call malloc_info(0, $__f)
  call fclose($__f)
```

Answer (score 2):

To debug STL, add content to .gdbinit, follow these instructions:

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html#STLDEREF