# How to close layout SRC windows in gdb?

Tags: debugging, gdb

When debugging with GDB， i usually using layout src to check my code. But when i open it, i don't know how to close it. It seems that there are some other layout, and when open a new layout, it will split the window, but i still can not found a command to merge the splitted windows.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can always leave or enter TUI at any time durring debug session. For example you can do it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> key binding. [25.2 TUI Key Bindings](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI-Keys.html#TUI-Keys).

Comment: I'm living a VM linux on Windows. When enter into TUI mode, all `ctrl-x ..` do not work. So that I can't quit TUI using `ctrl-x a`. I'm looking for a command like `focus src` to let me leave TUI.

Comment: I found a solution from  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953720/multiple-problems-with-gdbs-tui-mode. I used to enter into TUI mode by firstly running gdb then hit `ctrl-x a`, in which situation `ctrl-x a` doesn't let me out. While if I start gdb with `gdb a.out -tui`, all things work fine.

Comment: ctrk-x a does not work if you are on byobu, used q to quit TUI.

Answer (score 21):

**vi Readline input bug**

In GDB 7.7, `Ctrl-x + a` does not work if you have in your `~/.inputrc`:

```
set editing-mode vi
set keymap vi
```

If I remove those lines it works.

This seems to be mentioned at in the following bug report: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15163

I have requested a workaround at https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb/2015-06/msg00009.html and Andrew Burgess replied that he had [just submitted](https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb-patches/2015-05/msg00559.html) a well received patch to add:

```
tui enable
tui disable
```

so in future versions we should have commands as an alternative to the shortcuts.

I have later tested this on GDB 8.1 in Ubuntu 18.04 and it worked perfectly.

But then I saw the light and moved from TUI to GDB Dashboard: https://github.com/cyrus-and/gdb-dashboard which is simply more powerful and less buggy.

See also: http://superuser.com/questions/180512/how-to-turn-off-gdb-tui