# Cannot leave tui mode with Ctrl-X A nor see program output in tui mode

Tags: gdb, tui

**Problem A**:

1. I start gdb in command line with "gdb test"
2. I press ctrl-x,ctrl-a before I do anything else
3. Then I set break point using "b main"
4. Then I start running the program using "r"

Till this point, if I press the Up arrow key the src window will not scroll. Instead, something will appear in my command window - "^[0A".  If I try to refresh the screen with ctrl-l, "^L" is what appears in the command window.

I don't think this is supposed to happen. Under this situation I can't even quit tui mode with c-x,c-a ("^X^A" will appear instead). Am I doing something wrong? I realize this problem occurs so long as I use the "run" command inside the TUI interface. I can, however, use the run command in TUI if I start gdb with "gdb -tui"

**Problem B**

I can't see the output of my program in TUI mode. GDB's own output can be seen, but not that of the program being debugged. This occurs both when I enter TUI using ctrl-x,ctrl-a and when using -tui command-line option.

Is there any way to fix this?

I've read some TUI articles on the net and some people seem to use TUI "exclusively". I suppose TUI can work properly, it's just there's a set of rules that must be carefully followed?

EDIT: I use gnome-terminal in ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 10):

Run gdb with -tui option instead (https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=112660)

Answer (score 9):

**`~/.inputrc`** was the culprit in GDB 7.7 because of:

```
set editing-mode vi
set keymap vi
```

If I remove those lines it works.

This seems to be mentioned at in the following bug report: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15163

I have requested a workaround at https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb/2015-06/msg00009.html and Andrew Burgess replied that he had [just submitted](https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb-patches/2015-05/msg00559.html) a well received patch to add:

```
tui enable
tui disable
```

so in future versions we should have commands as an alternative to the shortcuts.

But then I saw the light and moved from TUI to GDB Dashboard: https://github.com/cyrus-and/gdb-dashboard which is simply more powerful and less buggy. See also: [How to highlight and color gdb output during interactive debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209534/how-to-highlight-and-color-gdb-output-during-interactive-debugging)

Comment: I am using gdb 7.6 (Centos 7) but "tui enable" and "tui disable" commands are not available. Just "tui reg". I tested in gdb 7.11 (Ubuntu 16) and these options are ok. Should I enable anything else in gdb to have these options?

Comment: @fcatho `enable` and `disable` were not yet implemented in GDB 7.7 when I wrote this, so I think the only way is to get a newer GDB :-(

Answer (score 1):

Change your terminal to get rid of your first problem. I used to use gnome-terminal my self, but then changed to terminator. Some terminals don't support keys like Alt sometimes (used to experience this in vim with some Alt+something maps)

You can change forcus to another window by 'focus winName', in your case, use 'focus src'
got this from [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI.html)

Not sure about your 2nd problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for, "focus next."  it switches you among (there can be more than two) the windows.  I'm sure there is a short-cut for this too.  Please note, this is almost the same answer as user1888039, so if you agree you should up-vote that answer.

Comment: The shortcut is "fs next".

Answer (score 0):

**Problem A:**
Use Ctrl+X then press a to enter or exit TUI mode.
Or as you mentioned run gdb -tui

**Problem B:**
Note that your program print could be ran over by the (gdb) prompt. In other words, it is possible that your program prints but the " (gdb)" is printed over it after.
To easily check if this is indeed the case, try to print either a line longer than 6 characters or multiple lines each time.
You should see part of your print.