# Control character in gdb tui

Tags: debugging, gdb, debian

From https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI-Keys.html
I'm trying to familiarize myself with gdb -tui and cannot get the control character to behave as expected.  What am I missing here?

(gdb) ^X^A
Undefined command: "".  Try "help".

Control + shift do not work either.  I'm using Debian Jessie with kde if that helps.  Is it possible this is a desktop interface problem?

Interestingly, control-c works to send the kill signal to the process. I can also suspend with c-z and go back to konsole.

Comment: while risking at sounding dumb (and because you are using so many different conventions for your control-keys: you do mean (and press) <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to enter/leave tui-mode, don't you?

Comment: and to rule out any interference with your desktop, you could try running `gdb -tui` on the terminal (<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>), where there's no X, KDE or whatelse getting in your way.

Comment: I have a makefile target which does "gdb -tui".  I run the make file target directly from bash in konsole.  Sorry if the conventions are confusting.  The "^X" stuff is copy/pasted after holding control and hitting 'x'.

Comment: but afaict you are running `make` from within an x-terminal(-emulator) - so within KDE. I'm explicitely asking to run it without any X (by switching to tty1)

Comment: that would be interesting to test, if only as a verification of an x conflict.  This is a vulkan app so x is pretty much a requirement.  I will definitely give it a try though.

Comment: I stopped X, same behavior.  See the accepted answer, that got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TUI Key Bindings sometimes do not work, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30763087/72178 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/30763033/72178.

As a workaround you can use these commands in recent versions of gdb:

```
tui enable
tui disable
```

Comment: That got it. Commenting out "set editing-mode vi" solved it.  I would have never figured this out.  Thank you